# Ask user to log into play store

Tags: android

I am doing an in-app purchase and if the user is not logged into the play store, I want to ask them to do so within the app and then proceed with the purchase. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't do this, and why would you want to?  The Play Store takes care of it all.

Comment: The app crashes for me. If I am signed in, it doesn't crash. I get a null-point exception. Addtional comments can be given if needed

Comment: Please start a new question since the right solution is to fix the crash.  Include the stack trace from logcat.  Dob't post code.  People will ask for the code based on the stack trace.